# Can I get the count of rows deleted through a OneToMany cascade relationship?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a OneToMany relationship between two entities, say Parent and Child, with cascade = CascadeType.ALL.

When I delete from Parent I get the number of Parents deleted but not of the affected Children. Can I get that number? How?

This is the rough idea of what I'm doing:

```
@Entity
class Parent {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    String field;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent;
}

interface ParentRepository extendes CrudRepository<Parent, Integer> {
    Long deleteByField(String field);
}
```

Can I somehow have deleteByField return the total number of rows affected instead of just the parent rows?

Comment: I didn't see such features in JPA. I think only custome implemetation. Select count before deletion, or delete children first

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - modifying the repository to

```
interface ParentRepository extendes CrudRepository<Parent, Integer> {
    Set<Parent> deleteByField(String field);
}
```

This returns all the deleted Parent objects. Then I can go through the .children in each Parent to see how many there are (were).

I fear that's inefficient though as it retrieves all the objects so if anyone has a better idea, I'd like to know.